# Extract datatype information from an interface instance

Tags: c#

Supposing we have two classes that implement a common interface.

```
public interface IContract
{
    int Type  { get; }
}

public class XClass : IContract
{
    public int Type  { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
}

public class YClass : IContract
{
    public int Type  { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Now, As you know, when we assign a class to the implemented interface, the interface instance contain all the data of the assigned class boxed inside.

```
IContract ic = new XClass();
```

There should be a way to detect the datatype of the value within the interface variable ic.

If(ic contains XClass datatype) Then ...
If(ic contains YClass datatype) Then ...

I'd be glad if anyone can help me to detect the datatype assigned to the interface instance. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you need to make this kind of check, it's possible that a refactor of your interface/classes would help make your code clearer. Declaring a variable of an interface type indicates that you require *only* the methods and properties of that interface. If you then need to specialize based on the implementing type, you might be better off adding a new method to the interface itself, which individual classes can implement as they see fit.

Comment: Thanks dlev for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
if (ic is XClass)
```

You can use the "is" keyword to determine the class.  Then there's always .GetType(), but that isn't as clean.

```
if (ic.GetType() == typeof(XClass))
```

Also, it's worth mentioning the `as` keyword.  If you want to declare a new object from a current object, guaranteeing it's a specific class:

```
var d = ic as XClass
```

If `ic` isn't XCLass, it will set `d` to `null`.

Comment: Right, the 'is' operator is very useful.Thank you Richard.

Comment: This is useful, but incorrect.  Adding a method to the interface is the way to handle this situation. If yo udon't own the interface, then creating another interface with an `IContract` getter and the extra piece is the way to go.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl I don't disagree with you, but that doesn't answer the question.  Also, the `is` keyword is great for sanity checks, filtering (.ForEach(c=> c is XClass)) and other uses.  Methods don't always solve the problem.

Comment: There's [`OfType(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method so you don't have to use `Where(c => c is XClass)`.

Comment: @Romoku Sweet. Thanks for the tip.  I'll check that out.

Comment: Your `as` syntax is way off.  It should be `var d = ic as XClass;`

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl Well, it seems to be working in my case since I just need it to check for simple, limited and known datatypes. Thanks

Comment: @cadrell0 Aah, thanks.  This was definitely not an answer I thought too hard on.

Answer (score 1):

'is' operator is used to get the type of the object dynamically at run time and 'as' is used to type cast between types.

The above examples will be helpful to you.

although if your classes implementation is same irrespective of the type, then you should make use of generics.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ic.GetType().Equals(typeof(XClass))) 
{ //do something }
```